# How do I apply css to all elements except when first child is of certain id

Tags: html, css

### Problem Statement

How do I apply css to all elements of a certain class except when first child is of certain id?

### Examples

I have html as follows:

*HTML Example 1*

```html
<div class="content-body">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*HTML Example 2*

```html
<div class="content-body">
  <div id="container-special">
  </div>
</div>
```

css as follows:

```css
.content-body {
  max-width: 1050px;
}
```

Now, I would like the css to apply only when the first child div is not of `id=container-special`, i.e, I would like the css to take effect only for example 1.

### What I have tried

I have considered css selectors `:first-child`, and `not`, but I am unable to figure out how to apply them for my case.

Any help is appreciated.

### Update1 [Solution]

Thanks to everyone who answered my question. Based on provided inputs, I used the following solution:

```css
.content-body {
  max-width: 1050px;
}
```

```
// called when component containing <div id="container-special> is loaded
fixParentContainerWidthOnMount() {
  const cr = document.getElementById('container-special')
  const parent = cr.parentElement
  if (parent.className.includes('content-body')) {
    parent.classList.remove('content-body')
  }
}

// called when component containing <div id="container-special> is unloaded
fixParentContainerWidthOnDestroy() {
  const cr = document.getElementById('container-special')
  const parent = cr.parentElement
  if (
    parent.className.includes('container') &&
    !parent.className.includes('content-body')
  ) {
    parent.classList.add('content-body')
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible because CSS is cascading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: As @mootookoi said, this cannot be achieved with CSS because you cannot apply styles based on child properties. There just no grammar for a selector that would do that.

Comment: Thanks. I will try some non-css approach for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use jQuery you could access the element like this:

```
$('.content-body > :not(#container-special)').parent().css("max-width", "1050px")
```

Or for normal JS you could set the CSS:

```
.content-body {
  max-width: 1050px;
}
```

And then remove it from the element that contains the element with that ID:

```
var cs = document.getElementById('container-special')
var parent = cs.parentElement

if (parent.className == 'content-body') {
  parent.style.maxWidth = "initial"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you have to use a combination of css selector types. You have to use child-combinator and :not psuedo class here. But this will apply the styling to all the other tags which come under content-body except the container-special div.

```
.content-body>:not(#container-special) {
  max-width: 1050px;
}
```

However if you want to prevent applying the style to that entire div. You need to make some changes in the HTML code too.

HTML

```
<div class="content-body" id="container-special">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-body:not(#container-special) {
  max-width: 1050px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply slightly change your markup:

From

```
<div class="content-body">
  <div id="container-special">
  </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="content-body has-container-special">
  <div id="container-special">
  </div>
</div>
```

which allows you to formulate

```
.content-body:not(.has-container-special) {
  max-width: 1050px;
}
```

If you cannot change the markup, you could add that class via Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const el = document.querySelector('.content-body #container-special:first-child');
  if (el) el.parentElement.classList.add('has-container-special');
})
```